# Macro variable creation based on date value in SAS

Tags: date, macros, sas

I have a list of company IDs and Dates and I want to run a macro on this list in such a way that for each date all the company IDs need to be considered as my macro filter.

For example, my list is -

```
 DATA comp_date_list;
   INPUT compno sdate;
   DATALINES;
    12490 20090120
    87432 20090120
    24643 20090120
    87432 20090119
    12490 20090105
    24643 20090105
    ;
    proc print data=comp_date_list;
    run;
```

Now, I have a macro that is as follows -

```
%macro1(compno=,sdate=,threshold=,fdate=,edate=)
```

Now The macro has to run for every comp-date combination in my list. But since this is to run on a very large dataset, running it n times will take a long time. So to reduce the runtime, I plan to make a list of compnos for a given date and alter my macro to produce the results for a date.

Now my question is how to create a macro variable that has all the compnos for a given date and which alters as date changes? am new to macro writing and SAS. So please excuse my ignorance. Thanks!

Comment: Using `by` processing is usually far more efficient than using a macro to iterate over all your values/parameters, providing you can construct your code appropriately. Can you provide an example of the macro1 code?

Comment: macro1 code is a large code that calculates some values for a large financial dataset. And my boss doesn't want to alter that section of the code.

Answer (score 1):

A `call execute` statement in a datastep can run selective code (in this case, your macro) after the datastep in which it was called.  For example, the following should work for you:-

```
proc sort data = comp_date_list;
  by sdate compno;
data _null_;
  set comp_date_list;
  by sdate;

  attrib all_comps_on_date length=$1000 label="All_comps_on_date: '|' separated company numbers for date";
  retain all_comps_on_date "";

  if first.sdate then all_comps_on_date = '';
  all_comps_on_date = catx('|', all_comps_on_date, compno);
  if last.sdate then call execute('%macro1(compno='||strip(all_comps_on_date)||',sdate=,threshold=,fdate=,edate=)');
run;
```

A note of caution though; `call execute` can play havoc with macros that themselves create macro variables (especially if *they* are using `call execute` statements!)

I can only echo @ChrisJ and add that while SAS macros can be useful, maintaining and debugging them is a pain and I only use them as a last resort.  Not much help of course with legacy code!

Comment: Thanks! This might be helpful. I'll try and let you know